# How to validate a list in Struts 2 with a condition? (Validation Expressions)

Tags: xml, validation, struts2, expression, ognl

Using expressions, I am trying to ensure either a list has at least one object in it (is not empty) or a checkbox is checked as true... Nothing I've tried seems to be working.

In my validation xml  file I've tried the following...

This returns false all the time, resulting in an error even when the list is not empty:

```
    <validator type="fieldexpression">
       <param name="fieldname">uploads</param>
       <param name="expression">chkAtch eq true or <![CDATA[uploads.length > 0]]></param>
       <message key="validation.atch.present" />
    </validator>
```

This results in the same as above:

```
<param name="expression">chkAtch eq true or uploads.length > 0</param>
```

As does this:

```
<param name="expression">chkAtch eq true or uploads not in {null, ""}</param>
```

This returns true all the time, but will display the error message if any field errors are present:

```
<validator type="expression">
    <param name="expression">chkAtch eq true or uploads.length > 0</param>
    <message key="validation.atch.present" />
</validator>
```

Any ideas on how I can make sure either the check box is checked (TRUE) or the uploads list is populated with at least one object?

Thanks,

EDIT:

My JSP:

```
    <s:file label="File 1" id="file1" name="uploads[0].upload" /> <s:checkbox name="uploads[0].refFile" />
    <s:file label="File 2" id="file2" name="uploads[1].upload" /> <s:checkbox name="uploads[1].refFile" />

<!-- omitted - labels and cosmetics -->
    <s:checkbox name="chkAtch">&nbsp;
         <!-- label -->
    </s:checkbox>
```

EDIT 2:

Relevant snippets from action class:

```
   private Boolean chkAtch;
   private List<LinguisticFile> uploads;

   public String confirmInput() throws Exception {
        if (hasFieldErrors()) {
            LOG.debug("[confirmInput] has field errors");
            return createInput();
        }
   // Irrelevant code omitted
   ArrayList<AtchObj> atchObj = new ArrayList<AtchObj>();
        if (uploads != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < uploads.size(); i++) {
                if (uploads.get(i).getUpload() == null)
                    continue;
                AtchObj atchmnt = new AtchObj(uploads.get(i)
                        .getUploadFileName(),//
                        uploads.get(i).getUploadContentType(),//
                        uploads.get(i).getUpload(),//
                        uploads.get(i).getRefFile()//
                );
                atchObj.add(atchmnt);
            }
        }
    //Irrelevant code omitted
    return "success";
    }

    // Getters and Setters

    public static class LinguisticFile {
        private File upload;
        private String uploadFileName;
        private String uploadContentType;
        private Boolean refFile;

        public File getUpload() {
            return upload;
        }

        public void setUpload(File file) {
            this.upload = file;
        }

        public String getUploadFileName() {
            return uploadFileName;
        }

        public void setUploadFileName(String fileFileName) {
            this.uploadFileName = fileFileName;
        }

        public String getUploadContentType() {
            return uploadContentType;
        }

        public void setUploadContentType(String fileContentType) {
            this.uploadContentType = fileContentType;
        }

        public Boolean getRefFile() {
            return refFile;
        }

        public void setRefFile(Boolean refFile) {
            this.refFile = refFile;
        }
    }
```

Another quick edit:

I should note that everything else works for this project, including other xml expression validators.. it just seems as though I can't properly refer to this list within an expression.

Comment: The difference is one is a field expression and the other is just an expression

Answer (score 0):

As far as you are using a list try below expression. `length` is used for arrays. `not in`  always returns true in your case, that's why the second expression is valid.

```
<param name="expression"><![CDATA[chkAtch eq true or uploads.size > 0]]></param>
```

or

```
<param name="expression"><![CDATA[chkAtch eq true or not uploads.isEmpty]]></param>
```

Comment: OK I gave both a shot and it is still giving me issues (its not triggering an error). I will update my question and add my JSP.

Comment: Why your class is static? Is it inner class?

Comment: Yes, that class exists within my action class.

Comment: You have to make it non-static public class in the separate file.